# get listview values after click on menuItem

Tags: windows, contextmenu, menuitem

how to pick up the values of a listview done in WindowsPhone 8.1 then click on a MenuFlyoutItem. Example I have a listview with id, name and telephone after holding the list to appear MenuFlyoutItem want to click on a menu option and know the values of the id, name and telephone number of the line selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this question was answered many times but I will try to give you a solution.
You can add flyout to ItemTemplate of your ListView, like this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate> 
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Refresh" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Share" />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now, MenuFlyoutItem has event named "Click" so if you are using a "code-behind" approach you can create event handlers for your click events of menuFlyoutItems in page code. I believe that event args of this event will have information about which item was clicked.

Please look at this blog note I found, it may be useful for you:
http://igrali.com/2014/04/28/show-context-menu-using-menuflyout-windows-phone-8-1/